# Python nonblocking server

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I try to write simple nonblocking http server.
I can't manage to all routines (Task1, Task2 and server) run simultaneous. Whatewer I do the server block.

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web


async def Task1():
    for i in range(100):
        print ('Task-1',i)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def Task2():
    for i in range(100):
        print ('Task-2',i)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(text=text)



app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', handle), web.get('/{name}', handle)])


loop=asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.create_task(Task1())
loop.create_task(Task2())
loop.create_task(web.run_app(app)) #with this line commented task1/2 works
loop.run_forever()
```

The expected result should be printed on terminal while server runs.
But I got terminal output OR server running (commenting second line from end) but want both.

```
Task-1 0
Task-2 0
Task-1 1
Task-2 1
Task-1 2
Task-1 3
Task-2 2
Task-1 4
Task-1 5
Task-2 3
Task-1 6
---more---
```

Comment: Task1, Task2 and server should run in "parallel". But instead server is blocking and not allow Task1 and Task2 to run.

Comment: Did you try to call `web.run_app(app)` without `create_task`?

Comment: doesn't work. They block loop.run_forever().

Comment: I'm not familiar with `aiohttp`, but looking through the docs briefly there was some suggestion that you should be using [aiohttp.web.AppRunner](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.AppRunner) instead of `run_app`. See e.g. [this note](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/whats_new_3_0.html#application-runners).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`run_app`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.run_app) is a convenience function that sets up the server *and* runs the event loop until the server shuts down. It is a synchronous function meant for simple examples, and as such not meant to be passed to `create_task`. The only reason `create_task` doesn't raise an exception is because `run_app` never returns, so the final `create_task` doesn't actually get called.

To obtain control over the event loop and add other tasks to it, you can start your server using the [`AppRunner`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.AppRunner). For example (untested):

```
async def main():
    # create the application, as before
    app = aiohttp.web.Application()
    app.add_routes([
        aiohttp.web.get('/', handle),
        aiohttp.web.get('/{name}', handle)
    ])

    # add some tasks into the current event loop
    asyncio.create_task(Task1())
    asyncio.create_task(Task2())

    # set up the web server
    runner = aiohttp.web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    await aiohttp.web.TCPSite(runner).start()

    # wait forever, running both the web server and the tasks
    await asyncio.Event().wait()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to do little modification and got it working...

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web


async def Task1():
    for i in range(100):
        print ('Task-1',i)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def Task2():
    for i in range(100):
        print ('Task-2',i)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)



async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(text=text)

async def HttspServer():
    # create the application, as before
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes([
        web.get('/', handle),
        web.get('/{name}', handle)
    ])

    # set up the web server
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner)
    await site.start()

    # wait forever, running both the web server and the tasks
    await asyncio.Event().wait()


loop=asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.create_task(Task1())
loop.create_task(Task2())
loop.create_task(HttspServer())
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Note that `asyncio.run()` is the recommended way to start asyncio apps. If you don't use `asyncio.run`, then you don't need `await asyncio.Event().wait()` at the end of `HtspServer` - it was there in my version only to prevent `main()` from returning and consequently the program from exiting.

Comment: asyncio.run() is available only in latest python. Sugested remove works as should. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I sometimes forget that not everyone is using 3.7 or later. If you want, you can replace `asyncio.run(main())` with `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())` and still use the asyncio.run-compatible logic, and actually move to `asyncio.run()` once you can use Python 3.7 (or 3.8, the current latest release).

Comment: I can't add asyncio.create_task(Task1()) in your way. But does my way have some real drawbacks I'm unaware? As at least seems to work without trouble.

Comment: Sorry, you can replace `asyncio.create_task(x) with `loop.create_task(x)`, where `loop` is obtained as `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()`. There is no real drawback in the `run_forever` approach in current Python, but you will probably want to migrate to `asyncio.run()` later, and then your approach won't work because `asyncio.run()` creates a new event loop, unlike `run_until_complete` and `run_forever`.

Comment: I have trouble with asyncio.get_event_loop() as in my program all the thing is inside class. and asyncio.get_event_loop() doesn't work if not executed from main program afaik.

Comment: You can always use `asyncio.get_event_loop()` inside a coroutine (`async def`). That's what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

So this should be final solution?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web


async def Task1():
    for i in range(100):
        print ('Task-1',i)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def Task2():
    for i in range(100):
        print ('Task-2',i)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

async def handle(request):
    data = {'some': 'data'}
    return web.json_response(data)

async def main():
    # create the application, as before
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes([
        web.get('/', handle),
        web.get('/{name}', handle)
    ])

    # add some tasks into the current event loop
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(Task1())
    loop.create_task(Task2())

    # set up the web server
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    await web.TCPSite(runner).start()

    # wait forever, running both the web server and the tasks
    await asyncio.Event().wait()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Yes, that looks great, and is fully compatible with future use of `asyncio.run()` at top-level. Please note that you can [edit the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64091118/edit), you don't need to post a new one just to update or correct it.

Comment: I was thinking to do that but then I added as new program to keep workflow from what to what. Can be more readable but there are more to read as drawback.

Comment: How do you stop the web server once Task1 and Task2 are complete?